# Codeigniter updating data with OR condition in ID

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder

Hello I am a beginner in using Codeigniter. What I want is to update a data in Codeigniter with an OR condition to the ID.

Here is my MySQL query that I want to make happen:

```
Update message_received SET is_read = 1 WHERE msg_id = 3 OR parent_id = 3
```

I tried something like this:

```
$this->query->update_array('message_received', array('msg_id' => $_POST['read_my_message'],'parent_id' => $_POST['read_my_message']) , array('is_read'=>1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or_where` to apply `OR` condition in `CodeIgniter`, I've written a possible solution for your question([Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)).

See if it helps you.

```
$msg = $this->input->post('read_my_message'); // get the post data

$this->db->set('is_read', 1); // set the value of column
$this->db->where('msg_id', $msg); // first condition
$this->db->or_where('parent_id', $msg); // second contion
$this->db->update('message_received'); // table name

// Produces:
/* UPDATE `message_received` SET `is_read` = 1 WHERE `msg_id` = '$msg' OR `parent_id` = '$msg' */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `OR`. The references https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).